# How can i run php code within array?

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop

im using this php code (from a question on here):

```
<?php

define(TEMPLATES_LOCATION, 'templates/');

function TemplateFunction ($template, $replaces) {
    $template = file_get_contents(TEMPLATES_LOCATION . $template);
    if (is_array($replaces)) {
        foreach($replaces as $replacekey => $replacevalue){
            $template = str_replace('{$' . $replacekey . '}', $replacevalue, $template);
        }
    }
    return $template;
}

$keys = array(
    'TITLE' => 'This is page title',
    'HEADER' => 'This is some header',
    'GALLERY' => 'php while loop here'
);

echo TemplateFunction('body.tpl', $keys);

?>
```

The way my template file is set up is the following HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="gallery">{GALLERY}</div>
</body>
```

so where {GALLERY} is, the php script should replace that with my automatically generated `<li><img src="images/'.$filename.'"/></li>` which is being run in a while loop generated from a mysql request

what i thought might work is:

```
$keys = array(
        'TITLE' => 'This is page title',
        'HEADER' => 'This is some header',
        'GALLERY' => 'while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){<li><img src="'.$row['filename'].'"/></li>})'
);
```

but it doesnt :(

Comment: off topic for the question, but important: please be aware that the `mysql_xxx()` functions are deprecated and not recommended for use. It is strongly recommended to switch to the PDO library instead.

Comment: indeed, it's alright. I'm just getting this running how i need it to first then converting it into PDO / OOP :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re your code:

```
$keys = array(
        'TITLE' => 'This is page title',
        'HEADER' => 'This is some header',
        'GALLERY' => 'while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){<li><img src="'.$row['filename'].'"/></li>})'
);
```

I would consider it very poor practice to have PHP code embedded in your template data this way. Allow me to offer you a completely different solution...

Firstly, we need to encapsulate the code. The code you've shown above is trying to fetch data from a `$result` variable, but `$result` itself is obviously been set elsewhere. This isn't good, because if we ever want to change the way the gallery feature works, we would need to search all over the code to find different bits of it.

Instead, you should write the feature as a self-contained function (or a class if it's too complex for a single function), which would load the data, and process it.

Let's call that function `loadGallery()`. It might look something like this:

```
function loadGallery() {
    $output = '';
    $result = mysql_query('...gallery query here...');
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $output .= "<li><img src='{$row['filename']}'/></li>";
    }
    return '<ul>'.$output.'</ul>';
}
```

Obviously, it could be a lot more complex than that (eg you may want to paginate it, or offer category options; these would be written as parameters for the function). I've also not written any error checking, etc here for brevity.

Now that you've got that function, you can plug it into the template engine. You need to reference the function in your template.

You currently have template markers like this `{TITLE}`. In your code, these markers are swapped with plain text using `str_replace()`. That's fine. But in this case we now want to call a function instead, so we need to have a different kind of marker.

Let's write the gallery marker like this: `{FUNCTION:loadGallery}` instead of `{GALLERY}` as you currently have.

Now you can have an additional bit of code in your template engine that looks at these `{function:}` markers and replaces them with a function call. (You can keep the existing simple `str_replace()` method as well of course)

```
$funcReplaces = array(   //similar to your existing $keys array, but for allowed functions
    'loadGallery'
);

foreach($funcReplaces as $replaceFunc){
    $template = str_replace('{function:' . $replaceFunc . '}', $replaceFunc(), $template);
}
```

This will run the function and put the output into the template.

So that answers the question for you.

What I should point out, however, is that there are a *lot* of other issues that you need to think about when writing a templating engine, from both a technical and security perspective. The above describes a basic way to resolve the specific question at hand, but it *isn't* a fantastic all-singing all-dancing template engine. It's still just a pretty basic one.

That's fine, if that's all you need, but if you expect this system to grow, it's worth noting that this whole area is that this is very much a problem that others have already solved, and solved well. There are several very good templating engines available for PHP. I would suggest that your best course of action would be to investigate some of them, and maybe use one of those instead of writing your own.

Some that you could try:

- [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/)
- [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/)
- [Mustache](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for such an in depth answer! I'm only really using this system for my own projects, not going to be released commercially or anything. I'm using it to learn about php a lot more, so i will mark your answer as correct due to all the info you have given me. Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "execute PHP code within an array". You simply build the array programmatically:

```
while (/* something */) {
    $keys['GALLERY'][] = $something;
}
```

Comment: Ah okay, i'm new to this so don't fully understand it. I understand the while() part however, what are the second set of [] used for after the key? and also what does $something represent?

Comment: You *really* need to learn some basics. Start here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying `$something` is whatever you want to put into the array.

Comment: To be fair, i know php well. I've just not used arrays in this format before, it's new ground to me. so in this instance $something would be my <li><img src="#"/></li> im assuming?

Comment: this doesn't work. I fear i may be over complicating it. When i put the variable {GALLERY} onto the page, the script is to replace it with the repeating li. At the moment the script when calling {GALLERY} it replaces it with php while loop here, that string needs to be my images. Let me update my question

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following code that i've written to be the right solution to my issue:

```
$gallery = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
   $gallery[] = '<li><a href="'.$row['gallery_image_filename'].'" target="_blank"><img src="'.$row['gallery_image_filename'].'" width="'.$final_image_width.'" height="auto" style="margin: '.$other_margin.'px '.$gallery_image_margin.'px '.$other_margin.'px 0px"/></a></li>';
}
$gallery = implode(' ', $gallery);
```

i then can concatenate my $gallery variable into the `'GALLERY' => 'value'` value and it outputs all the database results as required. Thanks to all for your help :)

Answer (score -2):

Well, you can create an `class` with [`__toString`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) magic method which will process all images on your gallery and then return the string.

```
   class TemplateGallery{
       private $images = array();

       public function addImage($src){
           $images[] = $src;
       }

       public function __toString(){
           $str = "";
           foreach($images as $image){
               $str .= sprintf('<li><img src="%s"></li>',$image);
           }
           return $str;
       }
   }
```

Well, as the guy in comments said, it's too "hard", so, you can use an "pre-process" function, that will process your images array, and then return your template string.

```
$images = array(/* Put images src here */);
function processGallery($images){
    $str = "";
    foreach($images as $image){
        $str .= sprintf('<li><img src="%s"></li>',$image);
    }
    return $str;
}
```

And then call that function on your `array`.

Comment: Don't make this more complicated than it is. The OP needs to learn to use arrays, not magic methods.

Comment: So, go ahead and use some unsafe eval.

Comment: Well, another way is a pre-process function.

Comment: Thank you for this. I am also looking into OOP so this may come in handy soon. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: have updated my question to try and make it a little clearer. Will your solution still work? I'm at work at the moment so cannot test it out yet

Comment: Well, if you use `eval`, i think it will.